# How to get single data attribute inside XML node with multiple data

Tags: c#, xml

How to I get the USER ID inside this xml

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<TransaxRS>
    <User id=\"164\" status=\"1\" name=\"test\" surnames=\"auto\" email=\"test102@email.com\" password=\"*****\" language=\"English\" country=\"Philippines\" region=\"Metro Manila\" city=\"Makati\" postalCode=\"1227\" streetAddress=\"Valero St\" numberAddress=\"1220\" floorAddress=\"16\" phone=\"123456789\" birthDay=\"\" />
</TransaxRS>
```

I tried this code but it returns a null. TIA.

```
XmlNode paymentId = xml.SelectSingleNode("TransaxRS/User/id");
```

Comment: Have you tried XmlNode paymentId = xml.SelectSingleNode("TransaxRS/User/id").InnerText ?

Comment: Your xml is broken - [http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath)

Comment: @JamieRees That won't work. `paymentld` is declared as `xmlnode`. `selectsinglenode` function returns an `xmlnode`, and `innertext` will return a string.

Comment: @Eminem good point. Also the xml is not broken, that website is treating the escape's as bad XML

Answer (score 3):

Try this (Use @ for attributes)

```
SelectSingleNode("TransaxRS/User/@id")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are querying an attribute so you need to add @

```
XmlNode paymentId = xml.SelectSingleNode("TransaxRS/User/@id");
```